# Send Header and Data through Axios in react.js

Tags: reactjs, curl, axios

I am new to React I want to make a Post request in Curl to get an OTP.

```
curl -X POST "https://api.kaleyra.io/v1/<SID>/messages" \
 -H "api-key: <API_KEY>" \
 -d "to=<TO_NUMBER>" \
 -d "type=OTP"
```

I'm trying to use Axios to make the request but I'm not able to find a way to pass both header and data through it

```
axios.post('https://api.kaleyra.io/v1/<SID>/messages', {
         to:'<TO_NUMBER>',
         type='OTP'
         })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
      .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

How should I add the header to this ??
**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
const headers = {
  'api-key': '<API_KEY>',
}

const data = {
  to: '<TO_NUMBER>',
  sender: '<FROM_NUMBER>',
  body: '<MESSAGE>',
  type: 'OTP',
}

axios.post('https://api.kaleyra.io/v1/<SID>/messages', data, {
  headers: headers
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log() 
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```